# How to create a list of dictionaries with key:value format from a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebWXV.png)

The want the column headers as the keys without any quotes around them and the subsequent values in the columns as the values of the keys.

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv

with open('zinc3.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        print ("#1\n")
```

Comment: so don't print `row` without formatting, as it prints the dictionary. can you show us the input (as text, not image) and the expected output (also as text)?

Comment: You want headers as keys in a dictionary without quote...are the headers numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas library in python which can handle:

- reading the csv file: using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- converting it into a list of dictionaries : using [pandas.dataframe.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Here's a general reproducible example (you need to install pandas)

```
from StringIO import StringIO 
import pandas as pd 

data = """
col1|col2
1|2
21|2
14|2
12|42
10|2
1|27
""" 

# StringIO(data) to simulate a csv file 
# replace it with the name of your csv file 
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep="|")

print(df.to_dict(orient="records"))
```

The output looks like this:

```
[{'col2': 2, 'col1': 1}, {'col2': 2, 'col1': 21}, {'col2': 2, 'col1': 14}, {'col2': 42, 'col1': 12}, {'col2': 2, 'col1': 10}, {'col2': 27, 'col1': 1}]
```

For your specific case, you need to do the following

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("zinc3.csv", sep="|")    
print(df.to_dict(orient="records"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, given a file:

```
# test.csv
1,2,3
a_foo,b_foo,c_foo
a_bar,b_bar,c_bar
```

You can make a dictionary with numeric headings as follows:

```
import csv
import collections as ct


with open("./test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in row.items():
            dd[int(k)].append(v)
dd
```

Output

```
defaultdict(list,
            {1: ['a_foo', 'a_bar'],
             2: ['b_foo', 'b_bar'],
             3: ['c_foo', 'c_bar']})
```

You will have to replace the filename. The `DictReader` yields a dictionary for each row, where the keys are the headers and the values are the subsequent items from each column. Here we rebuild the dictionary by appending values to a `defaultdict`.  The keys (assumed numeric) are converted to integers.

---

For small files, you can condense this code with a list comprehension:

```
with open("./test.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
    [dd[int(k)].append(v) for row in reader for k, v in row.items()]

dd
```